# Cannot resolve symbol 'username'

Tags: android, api

i am new to android, i am working on a mobile app project with login and i want to call the login username and it shows error with **Cannot resolve symbol 'username'**.
I have tried to change it to empty, but it still doesn't work or i add **loginUser(String username)**. Does any experts know how to solve it?

android code mainactivity:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edUsername.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(edPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    String message = "All inputs required ..";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                } else {
                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
                    loginRequest.setUsername(edUsername.getText().toString());
                    loginRequest.setPassword(edPassword.getText().toString());
                    loginUser(loginRequest);
                }
            }
        });

public void loginUser(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall = ApiClient.getService().loginUser(username); //<-error here
        loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Visitor.class).putExtra("data",loginResponse));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    String message = "An error occurred please try again later... ";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                String message = t.getLocalizedMessage();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

android code interface:

```
public interface UserService {

    @GET("Person/")
    Call<LoginResponse> loginUser(@Query("username") String username);
}
```

api:

```
 public SqlConnection mainconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString);

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUsers()
        {
            List<People> list = new List<People>();
            string sqlquery = "Select LoginID, PersonEye, username, password from tblLogin";
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, mainconn))
            {
                mainconn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(new People()
                    {
                        LoginID = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0)),
                        PersonEye = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(1)),
                        username = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(2)),
                        password = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(3))
                    });
                }
            }
            return Ok(list);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetuserName(string username)
        {
            List<People> list = new List<People>();
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select LoginID, PersonEye, username, password from tblLogin where charindex(@name, username) = 1", mainconn))
            {
                mainconn.Open();
                com.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                com.Parameters["@name"].Value = username.ToString();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new People()
                        {
                            LoginID = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0)),
                            PersonEye = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(1)),
                            username = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(2)),
                            password = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(3))
                        });
                    }
                }
                return Ok(list);
            }
        }
```

login response:

```
    private String username;
    private List<LoginRequest> loginRequests = null;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<LoginRequest> getLoginRequests(){
        return loginRequests;
    }

    public void setLoginRequests(List<LoginRequest> loginRequests) {
        this.loginRequests = loginRequests;
    }
```

login request:

```
private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

apiclient:

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://180.20.133.5/")
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

    public static UserService getService() {
        UserService userService = getRetrofit().create(UserService.class);

        return userService;
    }
```

Comment: LoginRequest loginRequest. This request may contain username. Get user name from this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the word `username` that you have never defined.
What's `username`?
You haven't published the definition of `LoginRequest` but maybe the username is in there.

So you need to access it using `loginRequest.username`

Comment: it gives error with expected begin object but was begin array

Comment: that's a different error and it is in the handling of the response I guess. By the way any reason why you are not using retrofit?

Comment: i have used retrofit to make the call method

Comment: So check whether the LoginResponse is correct. Where/when do you get the `expected begin object but was begin array` error

Comment: when i test the app try to login